# Merge similar JSON messages into one using jolt

Tags: jolt

some help required for a jolt transformation that I am trying to achieve. Mainly I need to retain the `key_id` and contacts element and then group all elements in contacts into an array. This to merge multiple JSON messages into one batch json group
I have this input

```json
[
  {
    "key_id": "436",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "436": "aaaa-10f2-4cc3-820c-444444444",
        "1378": "2021-11-08",
        "1381": "2",
        "1421": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key_id": "436",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "436": "1111111111-e213-4c90-a8e8-6666gtggggf",
        "1378": "2021-11-09",
        "1381": "2",
        "1421": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key_id": "436",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "436": "xxxxxxxx-e213-4c90-a8e8-xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "1378": "2021-11-05",
        "1381": "2",
        "1421": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And would like to transform it with jolt into something like this

```json
[
  {
    "key_id": "436",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "436": "aaaa-10f2-4cc3-820c-444444444",
        "1378": "2021-11-08",
        "1381": "2",
        "1421": "1"
      },
      {
        "436": "1111111111-e213-4c90-a8e8-6666gtggggf",
        "1378": "2021-11-09",
        "1381": "2",
        "1421": "1"
      },
      {
        "436": "xxxxxxxx-e213-4c90-a8e8-xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "1378": "2021-11-05",
        "1381": "2",
        "1421": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried multiple transformations, but no luck so far. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformation spec in order to combine the sub-objects of the
`contacts` array respectively while retain all identical elements of `key_id`, and then pick leftmost `key_id` through use of **cardinality** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[0].&",
        "contacts": {
          "*": "[0].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key_id": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: you're welcome @steveciantar , have a nice study!